# PHP UPDATE with if and else statement

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need a little help with my script, I am making a library sign in/out and page and I have it working so that it posts the form when they sign in and out, but i want to make it to where if they are trying to sign out and they actually never signed in it would pop-up a js alert tell them that and I can't quite get it.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("connect.php");
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Winnipeg");
    $date = ("m-d-Y");
    $timeout = date("g:i:s a");

    //search for existing entries
    if ("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM signin_out WHERE
    lname='".$_POST['lastname']."' AND fname='".$_POST['firstname']."' 
    AND date='".$date."')") {

        //if they exist run this
        mysql_query("UPDATE signin_out SET timeout='" . $timeout . "' 
            WHERE lname='" . $_POST['lastname'] . "' 
            AND fname='" . $_POST['firstname'] . "' AND timeout='' ");
        header("Location: ../index.html");

        //if they don't exist run this
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.html");
        echo "<script type='text/javascipt'>\n";
        echo "alert('You did not sign in!');\n";
        echo "</script>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does it inter the 'they exist' block when they don't? Or are things just not outputting correctly?

Comment: header("location...") will redirect the page before that script is ever called. Yo ushould instead redirect to index with a get var or something. like index.php?exist=no then use that get var to display an error instead of an invasive js alert

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right. `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables should **never** be interpolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP [`Location` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) already sends them to `../index.html` long before the JavaScript gets `echo`ed out. You need to have a `logout.php` page with that JavaScript or a `$_GET` variable for the page you redirect them to, and trigger the alert box there.

For instance:

```
...
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php?notloggedin');
}
```

And somewhere in your `index.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['notloggedin'])) {
    echo '<script>alert("You did not sign in!");</script>';
}
?>
```

Although I find that an `alert` box is rather intrusive, I'd rather do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['notloggedin'])) {
    echo '<p><strong>You did not sign in!</strong></p>';
}
?>
```